# Custom Image upload field resulting in error

Tags: magento2, custom-options, image-upload

I'm using this code to upload images to a custom field in the admin panel:

```
 <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">page</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Hero Image</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
                <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item>
                <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">Company_CmsPage/image-preview</item>
                <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="Company_CmsPage/hero_image/upload"/>
                </item>
  </item>
```

When images are uploaded I get the following error:
*A technical problem with the server created an error. Try again to continue what you were doing. If the problem persists, try again later.*

Here is controller code Controller/Adminhtml/Cms/Upload.php

```
namespace ISM\CmsPage\Controller\Adminhtml\Cms\Heroimage;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Upload extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    /**
     * Image uploader
     *
     * @var \[Vendor]\[Module]\Model\ImageUploader
     */
    protected $imageUploader;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader $imageUploader
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader $imageUploader
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->imageUploader = $imageUploader;
    }


    /**
     * Upload file controller action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        try {
            $result = $this->imageUploader->saveFileToTmpDir('hero_image');

            $result['cookie'] = [
                'name' => $this->_getSession()->getName(),
                'value' => $this->_getSession()->getSessionId(),
                'lifetime' => $this->_getSession()->getCookieLifetime(),
                'path' => $this->_getSession()->getCookiePath(),
                'domain' => $this->_getSession()->getCookieDomain(),
            ];
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $result = ['error' => $e->getMessage(), 'errorcode' => $e->getCode()];
        }
        return $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON)->setData($result);
    }
}
?>
```

I've checked Magento and Server logs but haven't found anything.

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide your controller code for image uploading. However I am providing two files. One is model file for uplaoding and another one is a controller.

**Step 1)**

Create the file **ImageFileUploader.php** under ***app/code/Company/CmsPage/Model/***

Please change following const as per your preference

```
const FILE_DIR = 'hero_image/banner';
```

**File** : *app/code/Company/CmsPage/Model/ImageFileUploader.php*

```
<?php

namespace  Company\CmsPage\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
use Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

 
class ImageFileUploader
{
    /**
     * @var UploaderFactory
     */
    private $uploaderFactory;

    /**
     * @var Filesystem
     */
    private $filesystem;

    /**
     * @var StoreManagerInterface
     */
    private $storeManager;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    const FILE_DIR = 'hero_image/banner';

    /**
     * @param UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory
     * @param Filesystem $filesystem
     * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory,
        Filesystem $filesystem,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ) {
        $this->uploaderFactory = $uploaderFactory;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->filesystem = $filesystem;
    }

    /**
     * Save file to temp media directory
     *
     * @param string $fileId
     * @return array
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    public function saveImageToMediaFolder($fileId)
    {
        try {
            $result = ['file' => '', 'size' => ''];
            /** @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\Read $mediaDirectory */
            $mediaDirectory = $this->filesystem
                ->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA)
                ->getAbsolutePath(self::FILE_DIR);
            /** @var \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader $uploader */
            $uploader = $this->uploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => $fileId]);
            $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
            $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
            $uploader->setAllowedExtensions($this->getAllowedExtensions());
            $result = array_intersect_key($uploader->save($mediaDirectory), $result);

            $result['url'] = $this->getMediaUrl($result['file']);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $result = ['error' => $e->getMessage(), 'errorcode' => $e->getCode()];
        }
        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Get file url
     *
     * @param string $file
     * @return string
     */
    public function getMediaUrl($file)
    {
        $file = ltrim(str_replace('\\', '/', $file), '/');
        return $this->storeManager
            ->getStore()
            ->getBaseUrl(UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . self::FILE_DIR . '/' . $file;
    }

    /**
     * Get allowed file extensions
     *
     * @return string[]
     */
    public function getAllowedExtensions()
    {
        return ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png'];
    }
}
```

**step 2)**

create (or update exiting Controller) file **UploadImage.php** under ***app/code/Company/CmsPage/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/***

**File :** *app/code/Company/CmsPage/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/UploadImage.php*

```
<?php

namespace Company\CmsPage\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;


................
................
................
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Company\CmsPage\Model\ImageFileUploader;

/**
 * Class UploadImage
 * @package Aheadworks\Rbslider\Controller\Adminhtml\Slide
 */
class UploadImage extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    
    ................
    ................
    ................

    /**
     * @var ImageFileUploader
     */
    private $imageFileUploader;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param ImageFileUploader $imageFileUploader
     */
    public function __construct(
        ................,
        ................,
        ................,
        ImageFileUploader $imageFileUploader
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        ................
        ................
        $this->imageFileUploader = $imageFileUploader;
    }

    /**
     * Image upload action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $result = $this->imageFileUploader->saveImageToMediaFolder('img_file');
        return $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON)->setData($result);
    }
}
```

step : 3
Run php bin/magento setup:di:compile

**Note** : make sure url part  of your UI xml match with the controller file

```
<item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
<item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="Company_CmsPage/hero_image/upload"/>
</item>
```

Comment: Followed directions, still getting error. Does the path need to be an existing directory? What is it relative to. Should it have special permissions?

Comment: which path did you mean? Image upload folder path? No image upload path (i.e. "pub/media/hero_image/banner")  does not need special permission. Can you log some date on admin image uploader controller to confirm the controller is calling .

Comment: Controller/Adminhtml/Cms/Upload.php
I added to the question.